# How to make a template class be derived from another if the templates are a subet of the other?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, variadic-templates

Let's say I have two template classes `Foo<A,C,E>` and `Foo<A,B,C,D,E,F>`.  I want the former to automatically be derived from the latter.  How can that be done?

My motivation for this:  I want to use `Foo<A,C,E>` and `Foo<A,B,D>`.  They need to be placed in some base class declaration.  But if I homogenize them into some `FooBase` base class, it will lose all the properties of `Foo<Ts...>` (which has template member functions, so I cannot make them virtual in `FooBase` and define the overrides in the `Foo` derived classes).  So if I just use `Foo<A,B,C,D,E,F>` as the base class definition, then everything should work out fine.  Below illustrates the problem at hand:

```
struct FooBase {  // Fruitless attempt to homegenize A and B defined below.
//  template <int N> virtual void run() = 0; // No good, of course
};

template <typename... Ts>
struct Goo {
    template <int N> void run() { }  // This needs to be called by Foo<Ts...>
};

template <typename... Ts> 
struct Foo : Goo<Ts...>, FooBase {
//  template <int N> virtual void run() override { Goo<Ts...>::run<N>(); }
};

using A = Foo<int, char>;
using B = Foo<double, char>;

struct Thing {
    FooBase *foo1, *foo2;
    Thing (FooBase* f, FooBase* g) : foo1(f), foo2(g) { }
    template <int N> void run() { foo1->run<N>();  foo2->run<N>(); }
};

int main() {
    A* a = new A;
    B* b = new B;
    Thing thing(a,b);
    thing.run<5>();
}
```

Comment: How about using partial specialization?

Comment: Are you constrained to using C++11? Also, what do you want to happen if the template parameters are not a subset of `A,B,C,D,E,F`?

Comment: Can you show content of class and minimal usage?

Comment: Sample provided.  I would expand the templates until they are a superset of the ones I wish to use, if it will guarantee being a base class.

Comment: You kinda painted yourself into a corner - you want type erasure and type preservation at the same time. In my humble opinion, it's hopeless - you can't have both, something gotta give.

Comment: Maybe just use std;:variant<A,B> and std::visit to carry out their methods if one is used after the other?

Comment: You provide an idea of a coded solution. But what is the problem to solve? For my it sounds like an XY-problem! If you can describe what your underlying problem is, I believe there is a ( much simpler ) solution.

Comment: Your example doesn't show the need of inheritance between `Foo<A,C,E>` and `Foo<A,B,C,D,E,F>`.